# Explain about linkages(external/internal) in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, function, inline, linkage

Explain about linkages(external/internal) in c++?
How does linkage differ for a function,constant,inline function,template function ,class and template class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=41

check section 3.5 in standard http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2798.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Can you clarify your question a bit?  C++ linkage is a pretty big topic and giving a complete answer in an SO post is probably a bit more information than you're looking for ([Litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/litb) may prove me wrong).

Here is a link which provides a general overview of linkage: http://gaubuali.wordpress.com/linkage-in-c-and-c/

Comment: Actually I am waiting for Litb answer

Comment: i really like that link too and i'm not going to even try to prove you wrong :) and thanks for all your praise mates :) you've got a +1 now

Comment: i'm soo sorry. but i guess i could only add "blah blah blah" as answer now that JaredPar already linked to a very nice article :)

Comment: @litb just keep in your mind about writing a post abt it.Take your own time.