# How to append content to a txt file

Tags: unix, command

I am in a unix env and I need to append below content to a txt file without starting at a new line:
the content is:

```
set value = 9.0.1.3 || set var = 12.4
```

the txt file content is:

```
echo on
set name = 'charlie' ||
```

but when I use the command 'cat', I can append the content to the txt file, but the content will start from a new line, like this:

```
echo on
set name = 'charlie' ||
set value = 9.0.1.3 || set var = 12.4
```

well, my goal is to get it like this:

```
echo on
set name = 'charlie' || set value = 9.0.1.3 || set var = 12.4
```

What command should I use to reach my goal? thx.

Comment: [Check this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602921/what-unix-command-can-we-use-to-append-some-text-to-a-specific-line-in-a-file

Comment: Thx, appriciate it very much.

Comment: This does exactly what you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936738/bash-cat-multiple-files-content-in-to-single-string-without-newlines

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '$s/$/ set value = 9.0.1.3 || set var = 12.4/' FILE
```

That is inplace editing `FILE` (by `-i`, if you need a backup, use `-i.BACKUPEXTENSION`). The 1st `$` after the `'` addresses the last line, then `s`substitute the empty `$`tring on it at the end of the line with your string.

If it should be done on other line(s) than the last, you can address the `s`ubstitute command with line numbers, regex, etc.

Answer (score 0):

By default `cat` is not putting any new line charecter in the end of the file. If you already have a newline character in the end of the file then that will be concatinated.

```
>echo "TTTT\c">test1
>echo "GGGG\c">test2
>cat test1 test2
TTTTGGGG>
```

Please remove the newline character at the end of your file and then run the `cat` command.

You can remove the newline character at the end of file using below command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{flag=0}{if(flag==1)print a;flag=1;a=$0}END{printf("%s",a)}' FILE_NAME >FILE_NAME
```