# Appending data to the end of each line in unix

Tags: unix

I have used the options which are mentioned in the Question: [what-unix-command-can-we-use-to-append-some-text-to-a-specific-line-in-a-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602921/what-unix-command-can-we-use-to-append-some-text-to-a-specific-line-in-a-file).

```
perl -p -e's{\n}{, extra information\n} if $. ==3' myfile
awk '{s=$0; if( NR==3 ){ s=s ", Extra Information" } print s;}' myfile > newfile
sed -e '3s/$/, Extra Information/' -i myfile
```

All these options are appending the data however this appended data is coming to next line i.e. if data is appended at the end of line 3 when checking the file, the appended data is shown beginning at line 4.

Could you please help me to get the data appended at the end of line 3 not as a separate line 4.

Comment: These commands should append to the end of the line. How can we reproduce your problem? Are you sure your text viewer doesn't wrap long lines? Try turning on line numbering.

Comment: Yes, I have used the line numbering and checked the data in the data file. I this showing up in the next line rather appending the data at the end of the line.

Comment: Provide your sample input file.

Comment: Affordable Benefit Administrators (ABA)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        715768GK Construction, Inc.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          129965                                            222 Irving Drive,Suite 222

Comment: Could you please let me know where can I attach few records of the file as it is not fitting in the space provided. However, I have provided a part of one record information above.

Comment: edit your question to include the sample data. Look for the grey link 'edit' just below the tag 'unix' at the bottom of your message. use the `{}` tool for format the data so it is easy to read. good luck.

Comment: a common problem is people taking files created in a Windows environment, moving them to linux/unix, and not running `dos2unix myFile ...`. This will remove the Ctrl-M chars from theCrtl-M, Ctrl-J line ending pairs that Windows likes to use. It may solve your problem, as your code looks usable. Good luck.

Comment: This issue is resolved. Thanks for the support, but have one more issue. After appending this data to the end of the line, I want to redirect this line information to a new file. Could you please help me.

Comment: It's not clear from your Jul 17 comment whether you want to put the entire contents of the modified file into a new file or just the lines that needed modifying.  If the former, then a simple redirection will do, as shown in the awk example ("> newfile").  If the latter, you can solve this in numerous ways, for example expanding the "if" test in the Perl script to print the modified lines only.  Or do something in the OS after processing, for example diff the old and new files.  Should be fairly trivial to do in Perl.